# Intercept elmah logging ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah, elmah.mvc

I would like to try to intercept and do some other processing ( export a database ) when elmah raises an error.Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

ELMAH exposes two events in order to do this: `ErrorLog_Filtering` and `ErrorLog_Logged`. `ErrorLog_Filtering` is called just before logging to the configured error log and `ErrorLog_Logged` is called just after. You will find documentation about [error filtering](http://elmah.github.io/a/error-filtering/) on the [ELMAH site](http://elmah.github.io/). `ErrorLog_Logged` isn't really documented, but you can see an example of it in this article: [Logging to multiple ELMAH logs](http://docs.elmah.io/logging-to-multiple-elmah-logs/).

With that said, you probably don't want to execute any long running tasks as part of `ErrorLog_Logged` and `ErrorLog_Filtering`. It will slow down your system. I'm not sure on what you are trying to achieve here by exporting a database on every error?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is way around

1.Lets Create a Project Name **ElmahMvc**

2.Install nuget package [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC/)

```
Install-Package Elmah.MVC
```

3. Raise an **Exception** .There you go access error log by your local url/elmah

http://localhost:20351/elmah

The saving database and Emailing is bit of configuration to take ....

Lets look at it

1.Download ELMAH script form official site

[ELMAH](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/downloads/detail?name=ELMAH-1.2-db-SQLServer.sql)

2.add a database named **log** and run the script

3.add a connection string in web.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="elmah" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=log;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

4.Add a elmah element in web.config

```
  <elmah>

    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="elmah" /> 
   <!--For Addtional Mail Config .Remove it if not need for mail on every error-->
    <errorMail from="waltoncrm@waltonbd.com"
           to="mrahman.cse32@waltonbd.com"

           subject="Application Exception"
           async="false"
           smtpPort="25"
           smtpServer="YourServer"
           userName="uName"
           password="pass">
    </errorMail>
  </elmah>
```

and mail additional

under System.WebServer

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod ="Network">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="yourgmailEmailAddress"   password="yourGmailEmailPassword" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Download my sample project and Elmah script with Visual Studio 2013 
[akash365.com](http://akash365.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/ElmahMvc.rar)

Note:if you donot want to crash your program or use it in asp.net web form Static ***[WebMethod]***
This seems perfect

```
try 
{
    //some web method code 
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
}
```